# How to have correct keyboard layout in XMing?

Tags: keyboard, putty, keyboard-layout, xming

In Windows, I have the following symbols entering on the upper row of keyboard, if switched to Russian and pressed shift:

```
Ё!"№;%:?*()_+
```

The same appears in Putty.

But if I press the same keys in XMing, the result differs:

```
Ё!"#*:,.;()_+
```

I.e. some symbols are changed and replaced.

I run `XMing` with the following command:

```
Xming.exe :0 -clipboard -multiwindow -xkbmodel pc105 -nounixkill -xkblayout us,ru -xkboptions grp:ctrl_shift_toggle
```

How can I fix the problem?